# Creating a plugin in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, toolbar

I want to create a toolbar plugin for Visual Studio 2015 in C#.

The thing is I don't actually know which project type to use there to create my own toolbar plugin.

I'm sorry if this question is kind of stupid but i'm new again to Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "toolbar plugin" you mean a Visual Studio plugin with a button on a toolbar, you need to create a Visual Studio Package:

New Project -> Installed -> Other Project Types -> Extensibility

Then select Visual Studio Package in the right panel.
You need to have SDK installed for that.

Comment: I mean a Plugin in the upper toolbar where are also the "save" buttons. I want to create my own toolbar menu with 3 entrys with different functions.

Answer (score 1):

*I want to create a toolbar plugin*

With `toolbar plugin` do you mean creating a `Custom Control`? If yes, then you should probably select a `Class Library project`.

or `User control in Winform` and place it in toolbar? Then you should choose a `Winform` project.